# Dukescript plugin not in Netbeans plugin manager

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I am wanting to install [DukeScript](https://dukescript.com/getting_started.html) plugin to my NetBeans IDE and for some reason it doesn't show as an available plugin. I can find it just fine on the [NetBeans plugin listing](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/57392/dukescript-project-wizard). It even has a symbol to show that it's certified and should be available in the IDE for installation.

Attempted Solution: I tried downloading manually from the site and I get a zip with a bunch of jar files and 2 .nbm files. I tried adding the .nbm files to the plugin manager manually I get the following errors.

The plugin javax.websocket_api is requested in version 1.0.
The following plugin is affected:       
    DukeScript Project Wizard 
Some plugins require plugin org.netbeans.html.ko_ws_tyrus to be installed.
The plugin org.netbeans.html.ko_ws_tyrus is requested in version 1.2.3.
The following plugin is affected:       
DukeScript Project Wizard

Answer (score 0):

The plugin was temporarily not available from the update center. It should be there again now, after we removed some unneeded depenedencies. Please try to install it again via the plugin manager inside NetBeans.

To explain your problem with manual install: The plugin consists of NBMs and OSGi Bundles (the jar files). You need to install all of them.